# Can I create an XYZ Tiles connection to terracolor imagery product in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, xyz-tiles

I would like to add a Terracolor basemap to my QGIS 3 project (http://www.terracolor.net) as an XYZ Tiles connection.

Is there URL service for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TerraColor is a paid service provided by Earthstar Geographics LLC. I'm sure their sales people would be happy to answer any questions you have about the types of services they offer. [Contact information is available on their website](http://www.terracolor.net/contact.html).